# Thin hanging under high load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, load, thin

We have a Thin + RoR with ActiveRecord + memcached + Postgres application that is using a pg gem to access the Postgres database.

We are observing that under high load thin processes suddenly become unresponsive one by one and never recover when the load subsides. Our database server, in the meantime, is doing fine – we can query the data and get response in expected time.

Things we have observed:

- We do not see slow increase in response time before we get in a bad state – the transition is sudden.
- We can get into that state with one or with multiple thin processes, which seems to eliminate the possibility of them deadlocking each other under load.
- When the load subsides, thin processes do not recover and continue to be unresponsive.
- Once hung, a thin process does not seem to issue any requests to the DB.
- gdp points out that when in the hung state, we have thin threads in sleep_forever state: 0x00007f75c78c85d2 in sleep_forever (arg=) at thread.c:848

Keeping in mind that this is 95% read application with more or less aggressive caching strategy (i.e. we do not have database transactions that can cause deadlocks), we are looking for suggestions on where to look.

Thanks so much for your help! Extra info:

Gems:

- gem 'rails', '2.3.11'
- gem 'thin', '1.2.7'
- gem 'pg'

Environment:

- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.2
- Thin 1.2.7
- Ruby 1.9.2-p290
- Rails 2.3.11
- Apache 2.2.14 (details below)

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:42:27
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/worker"
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
-D HTTPD_ROOT=""
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
root@a17:~# /usr/sbin/apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:42:27
```

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with the TCP stack in ruby:
http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5343

Try upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 or better.

Comment: Thanks so much. This looks very relevant - stack traces are identical - but after we upgraded ti 1.9.3, the issue still persists.

Comment: Hrm we ultimately switched from thin to unicorn which avoids this altogether - maybe it's still an issue in 1.9.3?

Comment: This is actually exactly what we ended up doing. We switched to unicorn, the issue no longer repros for us.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up switching away from Thin to Unicorn. The issues went away.